# How to expose arangoDB data in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, arangodb

I have set up Prometheus locally (with Grafana), for now I configure it to scrape metrics from my minikube. Now, I need to figure out a way to expose data from arangoDB data in Prometheus. I found this [documentation](https://www.arangodb.com/2020/03/monitoring-arangodb-prometheus-grafana/) but I am not sure if it's the correct one as it seems like it's for monitoring the arangoDB in Prometheus but what I want to do is to be able to get data from arangoDB database in Prometheus in order to see in grafana dashboard after.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried exposing arangoDB metrics to Prometheus, but I looked into the docs for ArangoDB and found

[ArangoDB docs][1]

[1]: https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/deployment-kubernetes-metrics.html#:~:text=The%20ArangoDB%20Kubernetes%20Operator%20(%20kube,port%208528%20under%20path%20%2Fmetrics%20.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I will checkout this document.